# How to use Session Container in controller action?

Tags: zend-framework2, session-timeout

I was searching on internet. I want to use session in Action. And I have codes:

in module.config.php:

```
return array(
            'remember_me_seconds' => 360,
            'name'                => 'zf2',
            'use_cookies' => true,
            'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
);
```

in Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Configuration');

        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
        $sessionManager->start();

        /**
         * Optional: If you later want to use namespaces, you can already store the
         * Manager in the shared (static) Container (=namespace) field
         */
        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
    }
```

In Controller:

```
    public function updatesessionAction(){

            $key = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('key');
            $value = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('value');

            $this->userSession = new Container($this->sessionNameSpace);
            $this->userSession->offsetSet($key,$value);
}
```

It run, but time expired always = 180 seconds. Not 360 seconds like i config.
I don't know the where have value 180. And what do i need to set it like config ?